# Freeing Object Error

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management, free

I am `malloc`ing an array of c strings. After releasing it, I get the following error:

`Assembler(87536) malloc: *** error for object 0x108500840: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Why is that? I am pretty sure I am doing the `malloc` correctly. I'm pretty experienced with memory management, but I am not sure why this is giving me an error. The array is should hold three strings, each of which is 2 characters long.

Here is how I am mallocing the array:

```
char **reg_store;
reg_store = malloc(3 * (sizeof(char*)));
if (reg_store == NULL) {
     fprintf(Out, "Out of memory\n");
     exit(1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    reg_store[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    if (reg_store[i] == NULL) {
          fprintf(Out, "Out of memory\n");
          exit(1);
    }
}
```

Here is how I am freeing it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    free(reg_store[i]);
}
free(reg_store);
```

Here is what I have in between:

```
// Keeps a reference to which register has been parsed for storage

int count = 0;
char *reg = NULL;
char *inst_ptr // POINTS TO SOME STRING. EXAMPLE: $t2, $t1, $a0

while (1) {

    // Parses the string in inst_ptr with dollar, comma and space as a delimiter.
    reg = parse_token(inst_ptr, " $,\n", &inst_ptr, NULL);

    if (reg == NULL || *reg == '#') {
        break;
    }

    reg_store[count] = reg;
    count++;
    free(reg);
}
```

I am printing out `reg` after I call `parse_token` and it does print out correctly. I am also printing out `reg_store[count]` and it does also print out correctly.

Comment: This code causes no memory errors for me with highest memory debug options set. please post your whole code including the thing in the middle.

Comment: I added the code in the middle. Please check it. Thanks

Comment: you do sizeof(char*) at the beginning, but then when you run your for each you call sizeof(char) instead. Is char a pointer in your project? If I'm right, in the first call you are getting the size of the pointer of char(been awhile since playing with c), instead of the size of char on your system.

Comment: Either that or that's correct, and you are de-referencing char, but then in your second call you aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
reg_store[count] = reg;
free(reg);
```

and later

```
free(reg_store[i]);
```

reg is already freed and you free it another time (not talking about the problems with using it later). to fix this replace

```
reg_store[count] = reg;
```

with

```
strcpy(reg_store[count], reg);
```

or as suggested in the comments, since you know its two charaters, its better to `memcpy` it:

```
memcpy(reg_store[count], reg, 2);
```

Comment: That was it! Shallow copied instead of deep copying the items. Rookie mistake. Thank you!

Comment: And I'd suggest using something other than strcpy, as it is a pathway to buffer overflow land.  I'd suggest strncpy, but it has some strange behavior of it's own.  Since you know the size is two characters, I'd probably say to go ahead and do a memcpy.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding some printfs (or use the debugger) to see the values of all the malloced pointers just after they have been malloced.  Then do the same just before they are freed, to make sure they are the same.  Perhaps there is some other rogue code elsewhere in the program that is stomping over memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the "in between" code, in particular, right here:

```
reg_store[count] = reg;
count++;
free(reg);
```

You allocated `reg_store[count]` with `malloc` during your set up, then you overwrite the allocated value with `reg` and then free `reg`. The result is a memory leak from the original pointers that were in `reg_store` and a double-free on each element of `reg_store` when you try to clean everything up.

You need to copy `reg` into the memory already allocated in `reg_store[count]` (watching the size of course) or don't allocate any space for the elements of `reg_store` before the "in between" code at all.

Answer (score 0):

The error was already pointed out so no need to write it again.
I can however point out that i don't like the way you are handling errors.

```
void freeRegStore(char** reg_store)
{
    int i;
    if (reg_store != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            free(reg_store[i]);

        free(reg_store);
    }
}

char** allocRegStore()
{
    int i;
    char **reg_store;
    reg_store = calloc(3 * (sizeof(char*)), 1);
    if (reg_store != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            reg_store[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
            if (reg_store[i] == NULL)
            {
                freeRegStore(reg_store);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return reg_store;
}
```

In this method, the function allocRegStore will return NULL if there was not enough memory without leaving pieces around.
Then you can handle this case in main and not in the allocation function itself.
I disagree with the use of printf and exit inside functions.

```
int main()
{
    char** reg_store = allocRegStore();

    if (reg_store == NULL)
    {
        puts("Out of memory");
        return 1;
    }

    ... do your stuff

    freeRegStore();
    return 0;
}
```

I can also say that the memory used by this program will never go out of memory :) i would not worry about that.